# Units of the quotient of an order

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $R$ be an order in a imaginary quadratic number field such that $disc(R)$ is prime to $n$. Further suppose that for every prime $p$ dividing $n$, $p$ is inert in $R$. Now let $A = R/nR$. **I want to show that $\#A^\times = n^2\prod\limits_{p|n}(1-\frac 1 {p^2})$.**

If i'm not mistaken by the chinese remainder theorem we have $A \cong \bigoplus\limits_{p|n} A/p^{v_p(n)}A$. So what we want to show is that $\# (A/p^{v_p(n)}A)^\times = p^{2v_p(n)}(1-\frac 1 {p^2})$.

When $v_p(n) = 1$ this is true because $p$ is inert in $R$ and so $A/pA \cong \mathbb{F}_{p^2}$.

I guess we have to use the fact that $disc(R)$ is prime to $n$ but I can't see how. **In fact I would be quite interested to know what this condition implies in general.**

Comment: Nobody has an idea ? :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K$ be the imaginary quadratic field and $S$ be its ring of integers.
Let $\tau$ and $d$ be such that $S = \Bbb Z[\tau]$ and $R = \Bbb Z[d\tau]$.

$R/nR = \Bbb Z[d\tau]/n\Bbb Z[d\tau] \approx (\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)[d\tau]$.
Since $n$ and $d$ are coprime, $d$ is invertible in $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, and we have
$(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)[d\tau] \approx (\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)[\tau] \approx S/nS$.
So $R/nR \approx S/nS \approx \prod S/p^{v_p(n)}S$.

Since $p$ is inert, it is a prime in $S$, and the non-invertible elements of $(S/p^{v_p(n)}S)$ are those that are a multiple of $p$. Their density is $1/p^2$, which proves that $\# A^* = \prod (1 - p^{-2})$

For a more explicit calculation, 
if $a+bd\tau \in (\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)[d\tau]$ with $\gcd(a,b,n) = 1$, then
$(a+bd\tau)(a+bd\bar\tau) = a^2+abd(\tau+\bar\tau)+b^2d^2\tau\bar\tau = N$ is invertible in $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, and so $((a/N)+(b/N)d\bar\tau) \in (\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)[d\tau]$ is the inverse of $a+bd\tau$